# How do I get a checkbox value in datatable while using Paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, datatable

I have created a datatable with first column as checkbox for each row and I was doing an Ajax call while on successing I was trying to check the checkbox but it was checking only for the first page not for other pages.

Below is my code, please help me in that.

```
$.ajax({   
     type: 'GET', 
     url: '/PriceList/GetCheckedAccount/',
     data: { get_param: data1 },  
     dataType: 'json', 
     success: function (response) {            
           //alert("success");
      for (var i = 0, len = response.aaData.length; i < len; i++)    {       

         var id = response.aaData[i][1];         
         var chk = $(".chkBox" + id);    
        chk.attr("checked", true);    
     }    
  } 
});
```

Comment: are you using jquery dataTables??

Comment: yes i am using jquery datatable

Comment: This is actually a bug in `dataTables`!! It will not remember the pages which will not be displayed.. You can just cross verify this by allowing more records in a page!! **For ex:** if you are displaying 5 records, just display 10 records for time being and see whether they get selected or not!! I had this problem before which made me to change my design itself!!

Comment: if i remove the paging then it got selected. but with paging i am facing that issue. and i have more data in datatable so i have to enable the paging,

Comment: I can understand!! but that's the problem with dataTables!! you cannot select the records in `in-active page`!!

Comment: if i remove the paging and applying scrolling in that datatable then with sScrollX and sScrollY the header and body part are not aligned properly in Datatable.. i am stuck with that pls help me in that

Comment: Can you post an image of your dataTable with scrolling issue!! That can be considered to help you!!

Comment: how to post image here

Comment: You have a image icon at the top where you wrote question, below the title!! click on that and upload!!

Comment: i cannot upload image as it is showing me that u need 10 reputation

Comment: Or u can just go to postimg.org and upload there and provide the link here!!

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/447sk26yb/   u can check here the image

Comment: that's strange!! that shouldn't happen!! Check for any console errors!! are you loading it properly!! Try just by not giving scrollbar. I mean your scrollX and scrollY!!

Comment: ha ha ... either i have to give scrollbar or i have to give paging.. i have no other option and i showed u the issue i am facing with both the condition.,

Comment: yea I can understand but what I am trying to say is there must be something wrong in the way you load your resources!! just **[check out this](http://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html)**  scrolling of dataTables!! It's absolutely normal!!

Comment: thanks for your precious time and help.. it didn't work with me.. i think i have to go with paging and not to check that checkbox.

Comment: Hmmm your choice!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope draw.dt event help you to find out the control in each page redraw

Answer (score 0):

The issue of only being able to get the values of the check boxes on the current page comes from the use of DOM methods or querying without using the DataTables' API directly. It is not a bug as mentioned above, but is a matter of efficiency. The DataTable only stores the values on the current page. In order to access other values you must access the table using:

```
dataTable.rows().nodes().to$().find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){}
```

The datatable in this instance being your defined datatable.

Additionally, [here](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/) is a working version of checkbox values being stored and sent to the server

For more info see the [DataTable FAQs](https://datatables.net/faqs/index) and topics on DOM.